# How to export autocad file to png using java?

Tags: java, autocad

how can I export an AutoCAD file to PNG format in Java?

regards,

Wim

Answer (score 0):

If you have AutoCAD 2004 and later, use the JPGOUT or PNGOUT command.

Read more at http://www.ellenfinkelstein.com/AutoCAD_tips_create_jpeg_png_files.html#ixzz137C4193X

If not, you're going to have to duplicate a lot of AutoCAD code.

I suppose you'd use a Java BufferedImage and execute a lot of Graphics methods.